# Regex to remove leading 9 from a phone number, that isn't at the start of the line

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file with around 200 entries, each similar to this:

```
001     907123456789  
002     907234567890  
003     907345678901  
004     907456789012
```

I would like to strip the leading 9 from each phone number (i.e. the second item in the list) I'm struggling to find anything that will help me in this situation as the phone number isn't the first item in the line.

I've just noticed that the spaces in the file haven't copied through correctly, there are 5 spaces between the first 3 digit speed dial and the phone number.

Any advice on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: The number you wish to strip the 9 from always follows whitespace, or are there other possibilities like hyphens?

Comment: ... and do they all have the 001 prefix?

Comment: Nope, always following whitespace, but when I tried to search with preceding whitespace I get no returns (see first answer from Mads)

Comment: The leading number changes, they are speed dials, so 001, 002, etc up to 200, probably should have put in a couple of lines :)

Comment: Are you sure it's a space, not a tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command should do what you want:

```
%s/^\d\{3} \zs9/
```

Note that this will only work if the phone numbers have the exact format you give.  The regex is very specific, to make it a little more unlikely to screw up anything else in the file.

---

Since you said you were having trouble, I'll explain what's going on in this regex, so that even if you don't decide to use it, you can at least learn a bit.

`%s` means "do the substitution on every line."  This isn't really part of the regex.  It's a standard vim command.

`^` is an anchor, meaning "this must be the location of the start of the line" – or, in other words, "nothing may precede the following stuff on the line."

`\d\{3}` means "there must be exactly three digits here," which means that the first three characters of the line must be digits.

(space) means there must be a literal space next.  Go figure.

`\zs` means "actually start the match here."  The stuff before must match, but don't "select" anything previous.

`9` means there must be a literal `9` next.  This is what you'll match.

`/`, the last character, means "everything next is what you should replace the match with."  Since nothing follows it, it means "replace the match with nothing."

Done!

**Edit:**

Apparently, the data file in question did not have exactly one space between the first group of digits and the second.  To account for this, change the part of the regex that affects the match on the whitespace.

Thus, the space in the regex should be replaced by `\s\+`, meaning "match any whitespace character one or more times."  So, the regex would be:

```
%s/^\d\{3}\s\+\zs9/
```

Comment: is there a counterpart for \zs that dosn't include stuff after?

Comment: You got it.  `\ze`.  Very useful! Check `:help /\zs` for more info.

Comment: nice, guess ":help" is for vim, don't have vim, but \zs worked nice in sed

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm getting no returns on the search, the file has 5 spaces between the 2 items, but even putting 5 spaces in returns nothing. I get this returned:   E486: Pattern not found: ^\d\{3}     \zs9

Comment: Weird.  I added 4 spaces (to make the total number 5) and tried it on the number `004 98577272884` (with 5 spaces between the two parts).  It worked fine.  If you want to make the number of spaces be "at least one" instead of "exactly _n_," where _n_ is some number, use `%s/^\d\{3}\s\+\zs9/`.

Comment: YES, THANK YOU!!! The second suggestion worked like a charm, thanks for hte answer as well as explaining it so well Riley!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all 9's preceded by a whitespace with nothing.

`'s/ 9//g'`

Comment: Good idea, thanks for it, just tried it in vim and it advised could not pattern match " 9" and if I used 'sed -i "s/\ 9//g" filename' it returns with no errors but no changes (I also tried without the escape character before the space to the same effect). i.e. in vim I used :%s/ 9//g and it returned E486: Pattern not found:  9

Comment: @Rumbles this may be because you're using `:s`, without the `%` range modifier.  This command, then, will affect only one line (though the `g` flag will make it affect the whole line).

Comment: I did try this with the range modifier and it returned pattern not found :/

Answer (score 0):

I've voted to close your question, because you haven't shown any attempt to come up with your own solution, you should try, and show what you did and what didn't work.

First create a regex to match phone numbers, which will depend on the type of numbers in your file, but for example:

```
001 9\(\d*\)
```

Then use that in a substitution.

If not all numbers start with `001` then adapt the regex to work with all number in your file.

You might find this doesn't work, because it incorrectly alters the wrong part of a line like:

```
001 1234001 99
```

In which case figure out how to refine the regex to match only what you want to match (don't just ask for the answer to be handed to you on a plate.)

Comment: While I did look at a few guides, none of them tackled making changes to leading characters that were not at the start of a line. So I was pretty much stuck on this regex.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `s/^([0-9]+) 9/\1 /`

tested with:

```
echo -e "001 907987654321\n001 80798765 94321\n2345 9079876 954321" | \ 
sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\) 9/\1 /'
```

got the output:

```
001 07987654321
001 80798765 94321
2345 079876 954321
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but when I run the command I get the following:

sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\) 9/\1 /' speeddials.txt
001 907123456789 
002 907345678901 
003 907456789012

Comment: missed the part about 5 spaces, but just as in Riley answer, add a + to match more then one space